# How to solve "build/envsetup.sh LUNCH_MENU_CHOICES[@]: unbound variable" when trying to compile AOSP from source

Tags: android, android-source

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > repo
chmod a+x repo
./repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-7.1.1_r6
./repo sync
. build/envsetup.sh
```

fails with:

```
build/envsetup.sh: line 508: LUNCH_MENU_CHOICES[@]: unbound variable
```

on Ubuntu 16.04.

Also mentioned at: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=135180

Answer (score 1):

On my `.bashrc` I had a:

```
set -u
```

Obviously `envsetup.sh` is not high quality enough to not have undefined variables or be a non sourced standalone script.

So either remove it, or add a:

```
set +u
```

to disable it.

You also likely want to get rid of:

```
set -e
```

but I haven't tested that.